# Needed simple script/loop/command for input command, execute and output within textfiles

Tags: command-line, scripts, execute-command

Suppose I have list of commands in text file as below (`cat cmdlist.txt`):-

```
cut
lshw
top
awk
sensors
```

Now I want to get simple information on that command by `whatis cut`, `whatis lshw` etc. respectively and print these out-put of `whatis <commadnd>` in text file say `cmdinfo.txt`

**Desired output of `cmdinfo.txt` (`cat cmdinfo.txt`):-**

```
cut (1)              - remove sections from each line of files
lshw (1)             - list hardware
top (1)              - display Linux processes
awk (1)              - pattern scanning and text processing language
sensors (1)          - print sensors information
```

How do I achieve `cmdinfo.txt` file with output of `whatis` for commands from `cmdlist.txt` Respectively?

*This is only **sample** txt files.*

Suggest simple script if needed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As simple as possible:

```
xargs whatis < cmdlist.txt > cmdinfo.txt
```

Comment: Or `whatis $(< cmdlist.txt) > cmdinfo.txt` using `bash` and avoiding `xargs`.

Answer (score 5):

Much simpler one,

```
$ while read -r line; do whatis "$line"; done < cmdlist.txt > cmdinfo.txt
cut (1)              - remove sections from each line of files
lshw (1)             - list hardware
top (1)              - display Linux processes
awk (1)              - pattern scanning and text processing language
sensors (1)          - print sensors information
```

Use the below command to write the result into a file.

```
while read -r line; do whatis "$line"; done < cmdlist.txt > cmdinfo.txt
```

Comment: don't parse the output of cat command.

Comment: I tested it on lubuntu 12.04 and it works fine. Also your simpler version works. Maybe I don't understand your comment :)

Comment: @Leiizia what did you do is `cat file | awk '{print $1}'`, what i did is `awk '{print $1}' file`. I think you understand from that.

Comment: [Useless use of cat](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27162/how-to-avoid-a-useless-use-of-cat-when-parsing-a-file)

Comment: Sorry, I don't use awk in my answer, where you find it?

Comment: awk is just an example..

Comment: Yes, now I understand the meaning, thank you. Your simplified version is the best version. Thanks again for improving my answer

Comment: And delete your previous answer... :-)

Comment: I have to completely remove the answer? or should I change?

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm new and do not yet know the rules of good behavior :)

Answer (score 3):

Very simply:

```
for i in $(cat cmdlist.txt); do whatis $i ; done > cmdinfo.txt
```

This loops through every entry (`i`) in the output of `$(cat cmdlist.txt)`, and runs a `whatis` on very entry. Example output:

```
cut (1)              - remove sections from each line of files
lshw (1)             - list hardware
top (1)              - display Linux processes
awk (1)              - pattern scanning and processing language
sensors (1)          - print sensors information
```

**N.B.** even though in many examples you will find `i` used, you don't have to use it - you can use most plain alphanumeric strings- e.g.:

```
for jnka127nsdn in $(cat input.txt); do whatis $jnka127nsdn ; done
```

To do it without parsing `cat`:

```
while read -r i ; do whatis $i ; done < cmdlist.txt
```

Comment: I appreciate using `for`

Comment: Your welcome - note other answers such as @xiaodongjie did (you could upvote them / choose those instead :)

Comment: try to avoid parsing the output of `cat` command.

Comment: @Pandya `while` command is mainly used to read  a file line by line. See the update of @Letizia's answer.

Comment: [Useless use of cat](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27162/how-to-avoid-a-useless-use-of-cat-when-parsing-a-file)

Comment: @AvinashRaj Can we use `for` instead of `while` to read a file line by line?

Comment: @Pandya Yes, *but* it will break if those lines contain any spaces or tabs (this can be worked around quite easily, but it's cleaner to just use a while read loop). Not a problem in this specific case, obviously, but in general using a for loop to read a file line-by-line is to be avoided.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
#! /bin/bash
in_file=$1
out_file=$2

while read command
do
    whatis $command 
done < $in_file >> $out_file
```

I have chosen to leave `stderr` untouched, since if you have a command in there for which `whatis` information is not available, you should be made aware of that (and look elsewhere, if needed).

Answer (score 2):

I think that you can get properly result with following command.

```
$ for i in `cat cmdlist.txt`;do whatis $i 2>&1;done | sed "s,: nothing appropriate.,,g" > cmdinfo.txt
```

In fact,

```
$ for i in `cat cmdlist.txt`;do whatis $i 2>&1;done
```

The command, first command's one part will show outputs as following .

```
cut (1)              - remove sections from each line of files
lshw (1)             - list hardware
top (1)              - display Linux tasks
.: nothing appropriate.
.: nothing appropriate.
.: nothing appropriate.
tr (1)               - translate or delete characters
```

you can do it with `whatis $(cat cmdlist.txt)`, but it's output includes following lines.

```
.: nothing appropriate.
.: nothing appropriate.
.: nothing appropriate.
```

above `sed` command remove some output lines you needless.

**Question** is changed as now.
If all of the lines of `cmdlist.txt` can be listed from `whatis`, Can use following command as the simple way.

```
whatis `cat 1.txt` 2>/dev/null > cmdinfo.txt
```

If you just need the lines that can be completely listed from `whatis`, Can use following command as the simpleway.

```
whatis `cat 1.txt` > cmdinfo.txt
```

**However** you can choose one way of various ones.

Comment: Odd. Since the 'nothing appropriate' line is printed to `stderr`, why would you pipe stderr to stdin and then strip it away? Better to simple redirect stderr to `/dev/null`?

Comment: okay muru, please read again his question.

Comment: He requires to process "." string in his sample text.

Comment: I figured the dots are [ellipsis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis). Even so, you can replace the command with: `whatis $i 2>/dev/null >> cmd.txt`. No need for the `sed`.

Comment: muru, okay, I already thought it as the simple way, But it remove "." line.

Comment: See the latest question edit...

Comment: Yes, it does. I am saying it is unnecessary and can be done in a simpler fashion (the command I posted in the comment above). Please try it. At any rate, it's fine. Cheers!

Comment: @xiaodongjie `. .` is only used for indicating upto last command **Edited** question

Comment: And I think that the dot lines can be needed for him.