# Passing contents of file on the command line for c++ program

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, c++

I have the following program (let's call it program.cc):

```
int main() {
  int x, y, sum;
  std::cout << "A program which adds two integers\n";
  std::cout << "Enter 1st integer: ";
  std::cin >> x;
  std::cout << "Enter 2nd integer: ";
  std::cin >> y;
  sum = x + y;
  std::cout << "Sum is " << sum << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

I'm currently writing a bash script that would take a file and push it through the command line as arguments being passed to this cpp program. As you can see, the above program asks for two inputs.

I know how you can pass the contents of a file for use as input on stdin. But how would you do this if you want to pass the contents of a file as arguments through the command line?

To elaborate, let's say file.txt is the file i'm interested in, which simply contains two integers on separate lines.

EDIT:
I tried the xargs command:

```
       xargs program.cc < file.txt > outputresult.txt
```

But this ends up printing what I have in cout, e.g.:

```
     A program which adds two integers
     Enter 1st integer: Enter 2nd integer: Sum is 2
```

I only want what is cout'ed AFTER all my arguments have been passed. How do I do this?

Comment: Or http://askubuntu.com/q/497159/158442

Comment: @muru I tried the xargs approach in the links you sent. The file that i save the output of the program to is saving what is being cout'ed in the cpp program. How can I stop that?

Comment: @E46 What is it you want in the "outputresult.txt"?

Comment: @Zzzach..."Sum is x" where x is the sum of the two args

Comment: you need to check if the input is a tty or not. Use `isatty` like in http://stackoverflow.com/a/5157076/592540

Comment: @muru neither of those is a dupe. xargs is completely unneeded here and there's no need to loop over the output.

Comment: @terdon "I'm currently writing a bash script that would take a file and push it through the command line as arguments being passed to this cpp program." Think again.

Comment: @muru you think again. There's no need for a bash script, the OP's program can read stdin. None of the linked answers help here, they only make it needlessly complex. Look at what the OP has done in the edit: `xargs foo < file` when `foo <file` would do just as well.

Comment: @terdon For all I know OP intended to modify the program to use arguments instead of reading from stdin. That's what they said.

Comment: @muru that would make it off topic, still not a dupe of a completely unrelated question. As far as I can tell, the OP needed to learn about i) input redirection and ii) the difference between stderr and stdout. Neither of which is really addressed in the dupes as you can tell by the fact that the OP's edit is just a useless use of xargs.

Comment: @terdon you're supported by an edit that wasn't made when I voted to close. Without the edit, with the program on one hand, and the line I quoted on the other, I was perfectly justified in voting to close.

Comment: @terdon In fact, given the line I quoted, I *will* still vote to close as a dupe.

Answer (score 2):

The way you have written it, you need to pass the *contents* of the file to your program, not the file itself (and there's no need for `xargs`, by the way). One way to do that is using [input redirection](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html):

```
a.out < file
```

For example:

```
$ cat file
4 
7
$ ./a.out < file
A program which adds two integers
Enter 1st integer: Enter 2nd integer: Sum is 11
```

Another way to do the same thing is to print the file's contents and pass the to your program with a pipe:

```
$ cat file | ./a.out 
A program which adds two integers
Enter 1st integer: Enter 2nd integer: Sum is 11
```

A much cleaner approach, of course, would be to write your program so that it can take arguments instead of reading standard input:

```
./a.out 4 7
```

Or, write it so that it can open files internally and parse them for its input data:

```
./a.out file
```

Anyway, in order to get only the last line in the output, print the rest to standard error:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  int x, y, sum;
  std::cerr << "A program which adds two integers\n";
  std::cerr << "Enter 1st integer: ";
  std::cin >> x;
  std::cerr << "Enter 2nd integer: ";
  std::cin >> y;
  std::cerr << "\n";
  sum = x + y;
  std::cout << "Sum is " << sum << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Now, run:

```
$ ./a.out < file > output.txt
A program which adds two integers
Enter 1st integer: Enter 2nd integer: 
$ cat output.txt
Sum is 11
```

Or, to give the values manually:

```
$ ./a.out > output.txt 
A program which adds two integers
Enter 1st integer: 4
Enter 2nd integer: 7

$ cat output.txt 
Sum is 11
```

Comment: Great answer! Why does whatever you give to cerr stream not get printed? Does it have anything to do with `std::cerr << '\n'`? How does it work?

Comment: @daltonfury42 it is printed but to standard error, not standard output. `> file` only redirects standard output and not standard error. That's why you can see the `cerr` lines in the terminal but not in the output file. The `std::cerr << '\n'` is just to print a newline to make the output look correct.

Answer (score 1):

As terdon pointed out already, to do this you want to either redirect `stdin` from a file (and call the program using e.g. `program <inputfile.txt`) or change your program so that it parses arguments passed from the command line (and call the program using e.g. `program 1 2`);

In the first case you want to suppress the first two `cout`s if `stdin` is not connected to a terminal, and in the second case you want to suppress the first two `cout`s, e.g., if, say, not enough arguments have been passed from the command line;

Speaking of the first method, you can check whether a file descriptor is connected to a terminal using the `isatty()` function (POSIX function defined in `unistd.h`):

```
int isatty(int fd);
```

If `fd` is an opened file descriptor connected to a terminal, the function will return `1`; If `fd` is not an opened file descriptor or is not connected to a terminal, the function will return `0`:

```c
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
    int x, y, sum;
    std::cout << "A program which adds two integers\n";
    if(isatty(0)) {
        std::cout << "Enter 1st integer: ";
    }
    std::cin >> x;
    if(isatty(0)) {
        std::cout << "Enter 2nd integer: ";
    }
    std::cin >> y;
    sum = x + y;
    std::cout << "Sum is " << sum << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This way the user will be prompted to insert the numbers only if `stdin` has not been redirected:

```
user@user-X550CL ~/tmp % ./a.out               
A program which adds two integers
Enter 1st integer: 1
Enter 2nd integer: 2
Sum is 3
user@user-X550CL ~/tmp % cat inputfile.txt 
3
4
user@user-X550CL ~/tmp % ./a.out <inputfile.txt 
A program which adds two integers
Sum is 7
```

Speaking of the second method, here's a very rough example on how to parse arguments passed from the command line (arguments passed from the command line are stored into `argv`, which is an array of pointers to a character, so you'll have to cast each argument to an integer, but don't use `atoi()`! Use something that allows you to check if the arguments are numeric or not. I used `atoi()` just for the sake of simplicity):

```c
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int x, y, sum;
    std::cout << "A program which adds two integers\n";
    if(argc == 3) {
        x = atoi(argv[1]);
        y = atoi(argv[2]);
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "Enter 1st integer: ";
        std::cin >> x;
        std::cout << "Enter 2nd integer: ";
        std::cin >> y;
    }
    sum = x + y;
    std::cout << "Sum is " << sum << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This way the user will be prompted to insert the numbers only if not enough arguments have been passed from the command line:

```
user@user-X550CL ~/tmp % ./a.out
A program which adds two integers      
Enter 1st integer: 1
Enter 2nd integer: 2
Sum is 3
user@user-X550CL ~/tmp % ./a.out 3
A program which adds two integers
Enter 1st integer: ^C
user@user-X550CL ~/tmp % ./a.out 3 4
A program which adds two integers
Sum is 7
```

Answer (score 0):

So there are a few things you can do:

1. You can output to file within C++ using something like [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/).
2. You can remove the `cout << "Enter...` lines in your code so the only output of the program is what goes into the file.
3. You can work around using the error output stream (cerr instead of cout) and manipulate the outputs accordingly. If you want cout visible and cerr in the file, do `xargs program.cc < file.txt 2> outputresult.txt` (using **2>** instead of >). If you want cerr visible and cout in the file, do it as you had it above with just **>**.
4. Keep the output as it is now, but run 2 more executions that removes the unwanted lines from your code:

`cat outputresult.txt | grep Sum > tempfile && mv tempfile outputresult.txt`

You can implement this with your code like this:

`./program.cc < file.txt | grep Sum > outputresult.txt`

This method requires newlines to be written, however, so you'd have to make sure that the output it each in new lines.

I would personally suggest using either the file management within C++ or the cout and cerr hack, depending on the use of the program.

Comment: Why use `xargs`? It doesn't do anything useful here. Also, there's no need for a temp file if you want to parse the output: `program.cc < file | grep Sum > output` will do it.

Comment: True, but I was going off of the commands the OP was specifying above. I'll add the shorter version. And yea, xargs isn't needed, but again, it was what the OP was initially using.